# Are both javascript undefined-safety-pattern equally good?

Tags: javascript

Having the follwoing 2 patterns to generate a reliable local variable with the name `undefined` that should contains `undefined` is any of the 2 patterns safer (less error-prone / breakable) than the other?

pattern1

```
 function(arg1,arg2,....,undefined)
 { 

 }
```

pattern2

```
 function(arg1,arg2,....)
 { 
    var undefined;
 }
```

Maybe I am just to worried, but the pattern1 type seems breakable by simply passing a variable to the function which then is assigned to the local variable `undefined`.

## PS:

Also it seems newer browsers (i.e. FF 33 / Chromium 37) do not allow this pitfall anymore

```
window.undefined = "omg";
"omg" == undefined; //true
```

indeed they produce this

```
window.undefined = "omg";
console.log(window.undefined); // logs undefined and NOT "omg" in FF33/Chromium 37
```

hence making the safety patterns superflous anyway.
To me it seems agreeable that window.undefined may never be reset (readonly and being `undefined`) and in effect I wonder why there has anyway been a browser implementation which allowed for this being-a-bug-only-feature (at least I cannot see a use-case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe I am just to worried, but the pattern1 type seems breakable by simply passing a variable to the function

Yes, and that is why this pattern is only used in IEFEs where you yourself are the only caller of that function:

```
(function(arg1, arg2, …, undefined) { 
    // …
}(val1, val2, …));
```

> Also it seems newer browsers do not allow this pitfall anymore

Yes, all engines that implement ECMAScript 5 don't allow this - the global `undefined` variable is non-writable just as you described.

> hence making the safety patterns superflous anyway

Indeed, using it feels a lot like cargo-cult programming. Everyone expects ES5 today anyway.

> I wonder why there has anyway been a browser implementation which allowed for this being-a-bug-only-feature (at least I cannot see a use-case)?

It was simply a lack in the ES 3 spec. This never has been a "feature", it simply had been forgotten to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

Both pattern will essentially produce the same effect and its third party library/framework which adopted this approach to minimize the accidental redifinition of `undefined`.
[`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.

Prior to ECMAScript 5/modern browsers anyone could configure/rewrite this variable to any value. This posed a problem with third part libraries/frameworks where

```
 undefined = 5;//now undefined is of type number    
 //code inside library
 (function (arg1){
   if(somevar === undefined){//unintentionally it will compare somevar to 5

   }
 })(arg1);
```

Thus to minimize the effect from global variables they adopted below approach

```
(function (arg1, undefined){//since only one param is passed the second param undefined would indeed will be of type undefined
    if(somevar === undefined){//it will compare somevar to undefined 
    }
 })(arg1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern you provided is incomplete. It's proper use is when creating inline closure, so that you ensure the correct value of `undefined` by not passing any value for the last argument to the closure function.

```
(function (undefined) {
    // ... your safe code here
})();
```

Then it is equal in consequences to the second pattern. However, the first pattern is usually the one that is used, because enclosing all your code in a closure is a good idea under any circumstances (to avoid leaking variables into global scope).